# Problema com SWITCH

Tags: c, algoritmo, switch, dev-c++, do-while

Eu estou com um problema no código de uma atividade do curso de Análise.

**A estrutura do meu código é essa:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int num,menu, i,result, primo;

do{
    printf("Menu de Atividades");
    printf("Digite 1 para verificar numeros primos\nDigite 2 para verificar o cubo do numero desejado");
    switch(menu)
    case 1:
        printf("Digite um numero para verificar se e primo: ");
        scanf("%i",&num);
        primo = 0;
        for(i=1; i<=num; i++)
            if((num%i)==0)
                 primo++;
        if(primo>2)
            printf("%d nao e primo\n", num);

        else
            printf("%d e primo\n", num);
    break;
    case 2:
        printf("Digite um numero: \n");
        scanf("%i", &num);
        result = num*num*num;
        printf("O cubo de %i eh %i", num, result);
    break;
    default:
    break;

}while(menu !=0)
}
```

Eu estou tentando fazer um menu para colocar 2 atividades aqui, a primeira é de receber um número e retornar se é ou não primo, a segunda é simplesmente receber o número e retornar o cubo.

Eu consegui fazer as atividades, mas estou tendo bastante dificuldade em terminar esse menu, pois não estou achando meu erro, e mesmo procurando no google não consegui resolver.

O programa que eu uso é o Dev C++ e ele está retornando que tem alguma falha no `Switch` que eu não consegui localizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na estrutura do switch-case, estão faltando as chaves.

```
switch(menu)
{
    case 1:
        printf("Digite um numero para verificar se e primo: ");
        scanf("%i",&num);
        primo = 0;
        for(i=1; i<=num; i++)
            if((num%i)==0)
                 primo++;
        if(primo>2)
            printf("%d nao e primo\n", num);

        else
            printf("%d e primo\n", num);
    break;
    case 2:
        printf("Digite um numero: \n");
        scanf("%i", &num);
        result = num*num*num;
        printf("O cubo de %i eh %i", num, result);
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: Realmente esse era um dos problemas kkkk, obrigado pelo alerta, eu tinha esquecido completamente. Mas eu achei mais uns probleminhas aqui tipo o scanf que eu não tinha colocado pra receber valor antes de abrir o switch. Mas obrigado.